# R - create a loop to create many tables by multiplying columns with one column

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am quite new to working with R and i am trying to create a loop that produces many tables.

I have two tables A (64 columns) and B(147 columns) with equal rows. I need to multiply every column of A separately with the full table B --> resulting in 64 tables. So A[,1] * B, A[,2] * B, A[,3] * B, etc.

I can not figure out how to do this even though it seems like a simple calculation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
results = vector(length = 64, mode = 'list')
for (i in 1:64) {
    results[[i]] = B[1:nrow(A),]*A[,i]
}
```

Comment: It is important to emphasize that your answer is done well because your storage object is large enough to contain all thre results (length = 64). @Red_24 one should always do this, as it would takes longer if you don't do so!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I believe this worked. I have a follow-up question, if you know this one too. Is there a way that I can assign names to the 64 sheets that i get? I have the names stored as a vector.

Comment: names(results) = <vector with 64 names>

Comment: Recent developments have made the code slightly more complicated. It turns out that the number of rows are not identical. I need to apply this loopt ONLY when the indexes match. This means leaving out the indexes that appear only in table B and not in A. Is this possible? Table A had 373 rows, table B had 564 rows. All the 373 in A correspond with 373 in B, but the other 193 should be left out.

Comment: I have changed my previous answer accordingly.

Comment: When I export the results to Excel, there seems to be no row names attached to the newly created tables. It seems to be getting lost in the multiplication, as A and B both contain them originally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lapply as a single line of code.  Here is an example.  Note that the lapply function multiplies each column of df1 by df2:

```
m1 <- 1:10
m2 <- 2 * m1
m3 <- 3 * m1
df1 <- data.frame(m1, m2, m3)
> df1
   m1 m2 m3
1   1  2  3
2   2  4  6
3   3  6  9
4   4  8 12
5   5 10 15
6   6 12 18
7   7 14 21
8   8 16 24
9   9 18 27
10 10 20 30
df2 <- df1

dfs <- lapply(df1, function(x) x * df2) # replace df1 and df2 with your dataframes.
> dfs
$m1
    m1  m2  m3
1    1   2   3
2    4   8  12
3    9  18  27
4   16  32  48
5   25  50  75
6   36  72 108
7   49  98 147
8   64 128 192
9   81 162 243
10 100 200 300

$m2
    m1  m2  m3
1    2   4   6
2    8  16  24
3   18  36  54
4   32  64  96
5   50 100 150
6   72 144 216
7   98 196 294
8  128 256 384
9  162 324 486
10 200 400 600

$m3
    m1  m2  m3
1    3   6   9
2   12  24  36
3   27  54  81
4   48  96 144
5   75 150 225
6  108 216 324
7  147 294 441
8  192 384 576
9  243 486 729
10 300 600 900
```